# Unable to execute this C function "list2set" to remove duplicates from a linked list. The function goes into infinite loop instead. What is wrong?

Tags: c

This is supposed to return the list with all duplicate entries removed. However, this goes into infinite loop. Kindly suggest what is going wrong and how to correct it.

```
list_t *  list2set ( list_t * h) 
{ 
    list_t * p ,* dup ; 
    if (h){ 
        for (  p =h ;  p  ;  p = p -> next  ){ 
            for (  dup = p -> next  ;  dup -> next  ;  ) 
                if  (  p  ->  given  ==  dup  ->  given  ) { 
                    h = deleteptr(h,  dup ); 
                } else 
                    dup  =  dup -> next ; 
        } 
    } 
    return  h; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line to see what happens? Use pencil and paper to draw the list and all the operations to perform on it at the same time. That will help you see what might be going on.

Comment: Tried the debugger but can't really figure out the issue.

Comment: Style guide: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be written with spaces (let alone double spaces) around them.
Writing `dup -> next` is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `dup->next`.  In general, the intra-line spacing in your code is erratic — that makes your code harder to read than it should be.

Comment: haha yes I made all the changes as told by Kyle Moore also the spaces. But....

Comment: The `if (h)` test is superfluous.  If you remove it, the outer loop will set `p` to NULL, check that it is not null and terminate the loop anyway.

Comment: sorry didnt work! :(

Comment: How do you populate your list? please provide enough code to compile and reproduce the Issum.

Comment: manually, one by one...i want to provide the full code but character limit!

Comment: We need to see the code how you add some value to your list. Your links might be broken. We don't need to see your whole code. Remove everything not related to the problem. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details about what you should provide.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue in the provided code is that the inner loop condition `dup->next` is causing an infinite loop. This is because the inner loop does not terminate when `dup` becomes the last element in the list, resulting in an infinite loop condition.

To correct this, you can modify the inner loop condition to `dup` instead of `dup->next` to ensure that the loop terminates correctly when `dup` becomes the last element in the list.

Here's the corrected code:

```c
list_t *list2set(list_t *h) {
    list_t *p, *dup;
    if (h) {
        for (p = h; p; p = p->next) {
            for (dup = p->next; dup; ) {
                if (p->given == dup->given) {
                    h = deleteptr(h, dup);
                } else {
                    dup = dup->next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return h;
}
```

By modifying the inner loop condition to `dup`, the function should now correctly remove duplicate entries from the list without going into an infinite loop.

Comment: Sorry but its still not working!

Comment: Could you let me know more details?